# Configure Cyborg R.A.T 9 on elementaryOS with X.Org X Server 1.11.3

Tags: xorg

I want to configure my `Cyborg R.A.T 9 mouse` to work with my installation of `elementaryOS (luna, 64 Bit).`
I used [this solution](http://techspheria.com/2011/02/how-to-fix-saitek-cyborg-rat-series-mice-in-ubuntu/?fb_action_ids=377565422319138&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=288381481237582) for the last two years, but it doesn't work anymore (I guess it's outdated). Newer post I found included creating a file `910-rat.conf` in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, but this folder doesn't exist in my installation. As I don't want to destroy it, I thought it might be better to ask if simply creating that directory and file would work.

> TL;DR:
>
> OS: elementaryOS luna (0.2 beta) 64 bit
>
> Mouse: Cyborg R.A.T 9
>
> Xorg X server version: 1.11.3

**Question:**
Is it ok to create the `directory /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and will the `conf files` in there be used or am I missing any steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an [article in the german ubuntuusers wiki](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/xorg.conf.d) saying that the directory is located in `/usr/share/X11/` and not in `/etc/X11/` .

So I just added the file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and it worked.

For further reference:
I added the file `910-rat.conf` to the folder `/usr/X11/xorg.conf.d/`.
The file contained the following content:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Cyborg R.A.T. 9"
    MatchProduct "R.A.T.7|R.A.T.9"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "Buttons" "17"
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 0 0 8 9 7 6 12 0 0 0 16 17"
    Option "AutoReleaseButtons" "13 14 15"
    Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection
```